# Cookie Across Project

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, cookies

I have a `Project A running in http://localhost:2385/`

and another `Project B running in http://localhost:40288/`

in **Project A**, i have a code

```
Response.Cookies["LuckyMe"].Value = "yeah";
```

and in **Project B**, i have a

```
Response.Write("Hi, " + Response.Cookies["LuckyMe"].Value);
```

Question, can i access the value "yeah" to another project via cookie?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

I searched the same thing over internet some time back, the only worthwhile link I found was this:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee799132(v=cs.20).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee799132%28v=cs.20%29.aspx)

Here the real logic on how to implement the crossdomain cookie is given.

Hope this helps.